# What is the internal format for the limit key representation in DB2 v9?

Tags: db2

I have tried to see the "limit key" column value in SYSIBM.SYSINDEXPART, but it’s in internal format. Then how can I see the value which is in internal format..?

Answer (score 0):

I know if you use IBM Data Studio (http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/) and look at the Property view of a table it has a "Data Partitions" column which will show you the ending value (or limit key as you call it). Unfortunately i do not know the SQL or db2 command behind this part of the Data Studio GUI.